# How do I disable net.lightbody.bmp (BrowserMobProxy) logging messages in log4j framework?

Tags: java, maven, logging, proxy, log4j

Im using BrowserMobProxy Embedded Mode on Java with Selenium.

How do I disable log messages from BrowserMobProxy appearing on console? Is it possible to disable it somehow in log4.properties or some other way?

Example of unnecessary log in console that always appear:

```
 /537.36
Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://something.com/styles/html5-touch-template/main-33a42.css
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.807057776.1475866489
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, 
Via: 1.1 browsermobproxy
2016-10-06 21:28:09 -- ProxyToServerConnection.write(ProxyToServerConnection.java:345) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0xe29d0002, L:/112.111.1.11:52907 - R:something.com/333.111.1.11:80]: Using existing connection to: something.com/333.111.1.11:80
2016-10-06 21:28:09 -- ProxyConnection.doWrite(ProxyConnection.java:228) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0xe29d0002, L:/192.168.0.10:52907 - R:something.com/184.180.124.162:80]: Writing: DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
GET /styles/html5-touch-template/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.otf HTTP/1.1
Host: something.com
User-Agent
```

Log4j:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE, CONSOLE
log=src/test/resources
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} -- %C{1}.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} -- %-10p %c{1} - %m%n
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=ERROR
```

Please help :)

Comment: Please provide more details such as the code that is generating the console output and the content of your log4j configuration file

Comment: @D.B.: updated my question with more details. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**BEGIN EDIT:**

I want to clarify that the following suggestion will only work if the class you're trying to control via log4j properties is actually using log4j to generate the console output that you're seeing. If it is not then you can't control it with log4j configuration.

**END EDIT**

According to your log4j.properties you currently only have 2 loggers configured. Those are the root logger and the org.apache.http logger. You could achieve your desired results in several ways, but I'll provide what I think is the simplest solution.

I suggest you simply configure a separate logger for the package or class that you wish to treat differently from the rest and then configure that logger according to how you want it to behave.

For example here is a simple log4j.properties I put together to illustrate how you can do this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout, R

#In order to treat the test.Main class differntly, 
#I create a separate logger and configure it to send messages to the rolling file appender only.  
log4j.logger.test.Main=INFO, R
log4j.additivity.test.Main=false


## general log
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=logs/general.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %t %d{ISO8601} %c{2} - %m%n

# Configure a console appender that will be used for messages of any level
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Here are some classes to demonstrate this configuration:

Main.java

```
package test;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.debug("here's some debug");
        logger.info("here's some info");
        logger.warn("here's some warn");
        logger.error("here's some error");
        logger.fatal("here's some fatal");
        Main2.main(null);
    }

}
```

Main2.java

```
package test;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Main2 {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main2.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.debug("Main2 here's some debug");
        logger.info("Main2 here's some info");
        logger.warn("Main2 here's some warn");
        logger.error("Main2 here's some error");
        logger.fatal("Main2 here's some fatal");
    }
}
```

When I run the `Main` class here is the console output:

```
 WARN [main] (Main2.java:10) - Main2 here's some warn
ERROR [main] (Main2.java:11) - Main2 here's some error
FATAL [main] (Main2.java:12) - Main2 here's some fatal
```

Here is the content of the log file:

```
 INFO main 2016-10-10 22:53:15,534 test.Main - here's some info
 WARN main 2016-10-10 22:53:15,535 test.Main - here's some warn
ERROR main 2016-10-10 22:53:15,535 test.Main - here's some error
FATAL main 2016-10-10 22:53:15,535 test.Main - here's some fatal
 WARN main 2016-10-10 22:53:15,537 test.Main2 - Main2 here's some warn
ERROR main 2016-10-10 22:53:15,540 test.Main2 - Main2 here's some error
FATAL main 2016-10-10 22:53:15,540 test.Main2 - Main2 here's some fatal
```

Notice how Main never prints to the console, only to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

@D.B. thank you for your explanation. Its more clear for me now. So that problem with logging from browserMob Proxy and from some other classes - was solved by excluding slf4j from browserMob Proxy dependency and some other dependencies, since log4j as main logging cant disable completely logging from classes that using slf4j.